# Facebook like button overwhelms IE7

Tags: javascript, facebook

I recently noticed that the Facebook like button on my site seems to overwhelm IE7, but not other browsers.  The browser slows down to the point in which it is unusable. I tripled the memory in my virtual machine to see if it would help, but it didn't.

Markup:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like show_faces="false" width="35" font="" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

If I remove these lines, the issue goes away.

I noticed that the loading swirl keeps swirling in IE7 (never seems to finish), so I opened Fiddler.  The page seems to refresh about once a second.  A GET request is made to refresh the page, and ?fb_xd_fragment is appended to my query string.

The referer header on all of these requests is http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_artiber.php?version=6.

JavaScript errors are also thrown.

Does anyone know if changing any particular settings on the Facebook tags fixes the issue?  Does anyone know of any workarounds?

I've posted a sample fiddler (this is my first one, so please bear with me): http://jsfiddle.net/jhoppe/yQdsT/ If I go to edit the text of the fiddle, in example, I can easily see how the page performance has degraded.  Paired with other content on my page, the performance becomes unbearable

Comment: Does it persist with the html or iframe version too?

Comment: @Amit it doesn't persist with the iframe version, which is good news.  I didn't bother looking at the HTML 5 implementation, because I doubt it would work well in IE7. I'd like to use Facebook's newer technologies, but the iframe version could be a good workaround

Comment: the html5 version stands better chances of working on ie than the fbxml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with the XML namespace

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

But then it didn't work in Chrome.

So I decided to use the user agent to display the iframe version for IE7.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/